# Change text opacity on hover and during transition in css

Tags: html, css

I have an image which contains text which is hidden initially(below example "hello" is hidden initally).

When I hover over the text it should show up.

Also I am moving the image from one location to another using "transition".

The hover effect for the text should remain same when the image is moving from one location to another.

As in the below example I want the text "hello" to have the above effect.

```
<div id="image-3">
    <img src="sample.jpg" height="110" width="110"> 
    <div>
        <p>Sample</p>
    </div>
    <div id="hello-text-right">
        <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

For transition of the text I have css like this. But in this case the text travels faster than the image to the final location.

```
#image-3 #hello-text-right{
    opacity:0;
}

#image-3:hover #hello-text-right:hover{
    opacity:1;
    transition: all 0s linear 0s;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated on this.

Comment: You forgot a comma between the id's in your CSS, should be `#image-3, #hello-text-right`

Comment: @Ason With a space, these rules are targeting the element with `id="hello-text-right"` as a descendant of the element with `id="image-3"`. A comma between the IDs would apply this list of rules to _both_ elements, which is not intended (the image should be visible initially).

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, you have several ways to define a color. One of them is using the color components including the alpha-channel:

```
#hello-text-right{
    color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
#hello-text-right:hover{
    color:rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

That is now black text in my example, but you can use any rgba-value you want to.

Maybe you want to set the text within the image element. To do that, i would suggest you make it a DIV using a background-image and place the text within this DIV. You then only need a transition of the image, the text will be placed relative to it.

Comment: What about during transition? This wont take care of transition hover effect.

Comment: How do you start that transition? Is this a javascript-based approach? In this case, you should change the class for that element. Maybe you provide some information about the transition and how it's done.

Comment: I have added css for this. It is pure css based approach. No JS

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how or when you're moving the image, or what interaction(s) you are attempting to enable.

The rule `transition: 0s linear 0s` does nothing (a transition that takes zero seconds is not a transition). Additionally, there's no need to specify a `0s` delay (the second instance of `0s`) as this is the default value.

In general, it's a good idea to apply transition rules to the element itself, rather than to the `:hover` state. Doing this will allow transitions *out of* `:hover` when someone moves away.

In the snip below, the text "Hello" appears if you hover near the bottom of the moving (or moved) image-div element. If you prefer to have the text appear at the same time as the image moves, delete the `:hover` from the end of `#hello-text-right:hover` and you will remove the requirement to hover the text itself.

```css
#image-3, #hello-text-right {
    transition: all 2s;
}
#image-3 #hello-text-right {
    opacity: 0;
}
#image-3:hover #hello-text-right:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
#image-3:hover {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
p, div span { color: white; }
```

```html
<div id="image-3" style="background:url('https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1312461204/sample.jpg'); width:110px"> 
  <p>Sample</p>
  <div id="hello-text-right">
    <span>Hello</span>
  </div>
</div>
```